# $G$ acts on $A$. Is it true that $|A|$ divides $|G|$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group acting on a set $A$. Both $|G|$ and $|A|$ are finite. If the action is transitive then $|A|$ divides $|G|$ (by orbit-stabiliser theorem). Is it true in general that  $|A|$ divides $|G|$ ?

Comment: No. Let $G$ be the trivial group, $A$ any set with more than one element, and the action be the trivial action.

Comment: Every $G$-set $A$ is a union of orbits. The sizes of orbits are divisors of $|G|$. In general, is a sum of divisors of a number also a divisor of that number? No - that should be apparently false. For instance. $2+3$ is not a divisor of $6$. Indeed, $1+1+1+1$ is not a divisor of $6$ (it is always possible to make $G$ act trivially on a set $A$ of any size, where the orbits are singletons), and $6+1$ is not a divisor of $6$ (it is always possible to have $G$ act on a set $A$ that is bigger than $G$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider $G = \langle (12) \rangle$ and $A = \{ 1,2,3 \}$. Then $|A| = 3$ but $|G| = 2$.